# Music playback control in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-music-player

I am working on an app, which has a View that replicates the Music Player widget. This view includes the title, subtitle, and 3 playback control buttons. I am displaying music title and subtitle, by getting it from onNotificationPosted Function. I am getting the title and subtitle from notification extras. Is there any better way of achieving this?
The main issue is how can i control the media playback as my app isn't playing the music. I want to make them work as any 3rd party kwgt widget works for controlling music playback. I want to send a broadcast to the system to play/pause, the next or previous music by clicking on buttons. How can I do that?
Thanks.